# Program receives SIGSEGV(Segmentation fault) signal only when I run it in debug mode

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, dynamic-memory-allocation, clion

I have this very simple c program:

```
#define Carta struct cartaStruct*

int main(){
    Carta carta = (Carta) malloc(sizeof(Carta));
    carta->seme[0] = '\0';
    carta->valore = 3;
    carta->posizione = -1;
    carta->next = null;
    carta->previous = null;

    printCard(carta);

    Carta carta2 = (Carta) malloc(sizeof(Carta));
    carta2->seme[0] = '\0';
    carta2->valore = 2;
    carta2->posizione = -1;
    carta2->next = null;
    carta2->previous = null;

    printCard(carta2);
}
```

where `cartaStruct` is a struct representing a card for solitaire:

```
struct cartaStruct {
    int valore; //card value
    char seme[20]; //card suit
    int posizione; //card position in a line of cards
    struct cartaStruct *next;
    struct cartaStruct *previous;
};
```

and `printCard` function just prints out the card value, suit and position:

```
void printCard(Carta carta) {
    if (carta != null) {
        printf("\nseme: %s", carta->seme);
        printf("\nvalore: %i", carta->valore);
        printf("\nposizione: %i", carta->posizione);
        printf("\n");
    } else {
        printf("La carta è vuota");
    }
}
```

Now, everything works as intended and expected when I run the main normally (both cards are printed with the data I assigned them and the process finishes with exit code 0), but when I run it in debug mode I get a SIGSEGV (segmentation fault) signal when I declare `carta2` and initialize it by calling `malloc`.

I know that segmentation fault means the process is trying to access some memory address that does not belong to it, but when am I doing that here? And why does it only occur when I run the program in debug mode?

I'm using CLion ide with CMake if that helps.

Comment: `Carta carta = (Carta) malloc(sizeof(Carta))` shouldn't this be `Carta carta = (Carta) malloc(sizeof(carta))` ? `sizeof(carta)` instead of `sizeof(Carta)`

Comment: No, @SourabhChoure.  There *is* a problem with the allocation size there, but the particular change you suggest makes no difference at all.

Answer (score 1):

This memory allocation

```
Carta carta = (Carta) malloc(sizeof(Carta));
```

is wrong. You need to write

```
Carta carta = (Carta) malloc(sizeof(`struct cartaStruct`));
```

That is you need to allocate memory for an object of the structure type instead of a pointer of the structure type.

Or you could write

```
Carta carta = (Carta) malloc(sizeof( *carta ));
```

Answer (score 0):

Other issues are in here:

1. Don't cast `malloc` in C, it hides a serious warning, argument to `sizeof` operator seems invalid

> ```c
> Carta carta = (Carta) malloc(sizeof(Carta));
> ```

Must be changed to:

```c
Carta carta = malloc(sizeof(struct cartaStruct));
```

or you can use this interlocking technique of using the pointer itself which will be receiving the dynamic memory to be used as the argument for `sizeof`

```c
Carta carta = malloc(sizeof(*carta));
```

2. Use `NULL`(uppercase) instead of `null`(Lowercase)
   [*Note: Only first occurrence of the error is reported, there maybe other places too*]

> ```c
> carta->next = null;
> carta->previous = null;
> ```

Should be changed to:

```c
carta->next = NULL;
carta->previous = NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

> And why does it only occur when I run the program in debug mode?

Because undefined behavior can manifest differently for more or less any reason.  And you *do* have undefined behavior.

> when am I [accessing memory that does not belong to me] here?

`Carta` having been defined like so ...

```
#define Carta struct cartaStruct*
```

..., allocations such as ...

```
    Carta carta = (Carta) malloc(sizeof(Carta));
```

... are incorrect.  You are allocating space sufficient to store an object of type `struct cartaStruct *` -- a pointer -- whereas what you need is space large enough to hold a structure of type `struct cartaStruct`.  When you thereafter try to access the allocated memory through pointer `carta`, you overrun the bounds of the allocated space.

You could fix it like this:

```
    Carta carta = malloc(sizeof(struct cartaStruct));
```

, but the usual recommendation around here is to use the variable receiving the pointer to determine the needed size, like so:

```
    Carta carta = malloc(sizeof(*carta));
```

This will give you enough space for an object of whatever type `carta` points to, even if you change that later.

---

As a side note, it is highly unusual to use a macro as shorthand for a type name.  It is better and safer to use C's built in mechanism for designating type aliases, the `typedef`:

```
typedef struct cartaStruct *Carta;
```